# I'm trying save data on local storage by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

> I have a select an option with some fonts and I need it when I choose the font and click refresh to my website,
> I wanna keep the changes.

```
<select id="myfont">
  <option value="open-sans">Defult</option>
  <option value="secondFont">Font 2</option>
  <option value="thirdFont">Font 3</option> 
 </select>
```

> I used local storage but it doesn't work !!? '

```
let fonts = localStorage.getItem('myfont');
document.getElementById('myfont').onchange = function () {
 document.body.dataset.font = this.value;
 localStorage.setItem('myfont');}
```

> 

```
[data-font="open-sans"] {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
[data-font="secondFont"] {
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
[data-font="thirdFont"] {
font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, 
Verdana, sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'string')
```

if you are trying to store a json object then you'll need to "stringify" it first

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify({example: true}));
```

to "get" the data saved then its:

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

however, if it's a JSON object and would like to use it as an object again. Then you'll need to parse to reverse to "un-stringify"

```
const temp = localStorage.getItem('key');
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(temp);
```

keep-in mind that this method runs synchronously. So, you may run into scenarios where the value is undefined or null and to resolve it you would use a function or lambda function (i.e., "anonymous" function) to make it async and use the  "await" keyword to await for the completion of the operation or function for example:

```
localStorage.setItem('key' JSON.stringify({example: true));
// assuming the storing process is done elsewhere.

async fucntion exampleMethod(){
  const temp = await localStorage.getItem('key');
  return JSON.parse(temp);
}

async function exampleTwo(){
 const grabSavedObj = await exampleMethod()
  ... 
 // The saved data is now saved in grabSavedObj where you can do something with the data.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ Abdo Adel
The obvioux error that you made is that you are calling `localStorage.setItem` with one single argument.

You need to add a second argument which correspond to the value that you want to set/store as you have only the key offered (**myfont**).

I am not 100 % sure about the value you want to store I guess it is

```
this.value
```

here is the code:

```
let fonts = localStorage.getItem('myfont');
document.getElementById('myfont').onchange = function () {
document.body.dataset.font = this.value;
localStorage.setItem('myfont', this.value);}
```

Comment: I excuted this in chrome inspector, I saw the localstorage. And it seeùs to work for me !

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.setItem expects two parameters. See the reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_setitem.asp).

```
localStorage.setItem(keyname, value)
```

In your example you would have to use it like that:

```
localStorage.setItem('myfont', this.value);
```